# regex dont match if it is an empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Currently, I am using `/^[a-zA-Z.+-. ']+$/` regex to validate incoming strings.

When the incoming string is empty or only contains whitespace, I would like the code to throw an error.

How can I check for empty string **using regex**? I found some solutions but none are helpful.

Comment: `if(string.match(/^\s?=*$/g).length > 0) // Not valid`

Comment: Please don't use the jQuery Validate tag when the code in this question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?! *$)[a-zA-Z.+ '-]+$/
```

Or - to match any whitespace

```
/^(?!\s*$)[a-zA-Z.+\s'-]+$/
```

The `(?!\s*$)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the string is empty or only contains whitespace.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s*$)` - no empty string or whitespaces only in the string
- `[a-zA-Z.+\s'-]+` - 1 or more letters, `.`, `+`, whitespace, `'` or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Note that actually, you may also use `(?!\s+)` lookahead here, since your pattern does not match an empty string due to the `+` quantifier at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Check if the string is empty or not using the following regex:

```
/^ *$/
```

The regex above matches the start of the string (`^`), then any number of spaces (`*`), then the end of the string (`$`). If you would instead like to match ANY white space (tabs, etc.), you can use `\s*` instead of `*`, making the regex the following:

```
/^\s*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for empty or whitespace-only strings you can use this regex: `/^\s*$/`

Example:

```
function IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(str) {
    return (str.match(/^\s*$/) || []).length > 0;
}

var str1 = "";
var str2 = " ";
var str3 = "a b";

console.log(IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(str1)); // true
console.log(IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(str2)); // true
console.log(IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(str3)); // false
```

Comment: Global flag is unnecessary.

Comment: Whoops, was for testing, removed it